# Tables recognition using Google Vision API

Tags: google-vision, cloud-document-ai

I use OCR function (`DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION`) of Google Vision API to process different medical documents. There are some tables in them. According to Google's documentation, there is a special `BlockType` for tables.

However, I can't get this sort of block in a response from Google even in a case when existence of a table is obvious. What is the reason of such behavior? Do I need to use special options or methods to detect tables using Google Vision API? An example of a table I tried to process:

[image: attachment]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out your question about tables in Google Vision API in Google Forum. The short answer: tables (as blockType) aren't supported now (10/21/2021) but there is a feature request with minor priority: [Google Vision API Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/117948935?pli=1)

I would recommend you to use Document AI: [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai). I checked and it returned meta info about tables.